# Regex matching curly bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking for help in matching the curly brackets in a regular expression pattern. 
I've tried different combinations of escapes, and symbol matching with little luck. Perhaps because it's Friday afternoon and I'm overlooking something; but your ideas would be greatly appreciated. The code below:

```
function stringFormat(str, arr) {
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var regExp = new RegExp('^\{' + i + '\}$', 'g');
        str = str.replace(regExp, arr[i]);   
    }
    return str;  
}

var str = '<p>The quick {0}, brown {1}</p>';

$('#test').html(stringFormat(str, ['brown', 'fox']));
```

I've also started a fiddle on this, http://jsfiddle.net/rgy3y/1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of trying to match a bunch of different numbers, why not just do it all in one fell swoop:

```
function stringFormat(str, arr) {
  return str.replace(
      /\{([0-9]+)\}/g,
      function (_, index) { return arr[index]; });
}
```

On your example,

```
var str = '<p>The quick {0}, brown {1}</p>';

// Alerts <p>The quick brown, brown fox</p>
alert(stringFormat(str, ['brown', 'fox']));
```

This has the benefit that nothing weird will happen if `arr` contains a string like '{1}'.  E.g.
`stringFormat('{0}', ['{1}', 'foo']) === '{1}'` consistently instead of `'foo'` as with the fixed version of the original, but inconsistently with `stringFormat('{1}', ['foo', '{0}']) === '{0}'`

Comment: Thanks Mike. Appreciate the recommendation and solves potential problems down the road.

Comment: I took your format function but I added it as a static method to `String` and used the `arguments` array instead of having the user pass in an array. http://codetunnel.com/blog/post/string-replacement-is-natively-supported-by-consolelog

Comment: Your link seems to be down @Chev. Just a friendly reminder: `arguments` is not an array.

Comment: Thanks, [here you go](http://codetunnel.com/string-replacement-is-natively-supported-by-consolelog). Also I know lol, it's an "array-like data structure" but I'm not going to say that every time I need to mention it :P. It's iterable, and that's all that matters here :)

Comment: Did "arguments is an array in strict mode function bodies" not make it into ES5?

Answer (score 9):

To get a `\` in a string literal you need to type `\\`. In particular, `'\{'` == `'{'`. You want `'\\{'`.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with javascript (or whatever) regex, but you are only matching expressions that contain only {*X*} (or only lines with that expression, again depending on your regex). 
'`^`{' + i + '}`$`'

Remove the ^ and $.